# The application showing slowly and sometimes is stuck

Tags: android, performance, animation, tablet

I developed an application, which contains several layouts with several views and diffrent aimations accuring while playing. It works great on tablet, but on a telephones it shows the animations very slowly and sometimes gets stuck, what can be the reason for that?

Comment: How are we supposed to help (without any code / log) exactly? Anyway, check your logcat for "skipped frames"...

Comment: I dont know what to attach, because everything works but not as good as on tablet, maybe big xml file can cause this? or big\small picture resolution? or maybe too many searches for views? I will check for what you said

Comment: Watch for the logcat. You are obviously doing this on the UI Thread that are bad, or loading too big resources. Both should be logged into the logcat, or explainable by code. You provided none.